# .NET CORE 2.1.403 SignalR Official Support for Swift

Tags: swift, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I have Developed a WebApi Backend Project on **.NET CORE 2.1.403** and all the webapi routes are working great. Now I have a requirement for a real-time update on iOS application developed in Swift.

I could not find any official library which supports SignalR. After searching I found out https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift which supports `.NET CORE` but there is no detailed documentation on which we can rely. However my Javascript client is working great with **.NET CORE**.

I have previously used [SwiftR](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR) with `.NET FRAMEWORK 4.7.1` SignalR and it worked fine.

As suggested on [GITHUB issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1213#issuecomment-407597462) there is no plan on a Swift client. Any suggestions in this regards would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, the comment on the issue says there *are* plans for a Swift client, but there's no milestone yet. Your best bet is to simply study the code in the third-party Swift client repo you found. It's unfortunate that there's no docs or insufficient docs, but ultimately, if you can't understand the code you shouldn't be doing this in the first place. Perhaps you can even help out the community by documenting it yourself and submitting a pull request.

Comment: @Pawel, your link requires logging in (I expect it's an admin-only link). Here is a working link: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2019/07/28/swift-client-for-the-asp-net-core-version-of-signalr-part-1-getting-started/

Comment: The link was incorrect - thanks for posting a correct one. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize this is a late reply, but for what it's worth, I've successfully used the https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift SignalR client in iOS, against an AspNet Core server implementation. The documentation on GitHub is a little sparse, but it is very simple to use. For example:

```
// Set up a connection to the SignalR hub on the servver.
private func connectToSignalRHub() {
    // Are we already connected to the hub?
    if !isHubConnected {
        let url = URL(string: "http://\(hostName):\(serverPort)/hub")!
        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder(url: url).withLogging(minLogLevel: .error).build()
        if let hub = hubConnection {
            hub.delegate = self

            // Set our callbacks for the messages we expect from the SignalR hub.
            hub.on(method: "ProgressUpdate", callback: {
                args, typeConverter in
                if let data = try? typeConverter.convertFromWireType(obj: args[0], targetType: String.self) {
                    self.onHubProgressUpdate(progress: data)
                }
            })

            // Start the hub connection.
            hub.start()
        }
    }
}
```

I'd be happy to share more details if you still need it.

Comment: I need more details. I setten up a class like yours you shared but nothings detected about connection state. I dont know what can I do? I logged the steps and it finishes "HttpConnection denit".

Comment: Are you connecting to a SignalR hub running in Asp.NetCore? The reason I ask is that the SignalR implementation in Asp.NetCore is not compatible with earlier implementations in Asp.Net, so be careful not to try to connect to an older implementation of SignalR hub. But, it could also be a multitude of other reasons why your connection fails, could you share more specific details?